# Django | getting circluar import error on ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Form and FormModel in Django for one of my application.
I created one Model as below **models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class ImageProcessor(models.Model):
    id_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image_dir")
```

I am using the form as below (forms.py)

```
from django import forms
from .models import ImageProcessor


class ImageProcessorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageProcessor
```

In terminal window I am getting below message, and I am pretty sure that it is because of

```
from .models import ImageProcessor
```

this import.

ERROR message:

> **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'img_site.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
> valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
> circular i mport.**

**Update 1**: (urls.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('np_imager_processor.urls'))
]
```

**Update 2**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SomePath\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\SomePath\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "F:\SomeProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'img_site.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular i
mport.
```

Comment: Share the `img_site.urls` module. Did you import the `urls` module somewhere?

Comment: paste the full output of the error (including stacktrace)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated the urls file details

Comment: @AnthonySottile please check updated traceback

Comment: On commenting this line it is working --> from .models import ImageProcessor

Comment: can you show what happens when you import one of those modules individually?

Comment: In the terminal, I am getting above mentioned traceback, and the site doesn't work. Individually they are working fine.

Comment: And what do you have in the np_imager_processor app urls.py file?